# Start edit with rowediting after a new record has been added to a store with autosync on

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

We thought this to be simple by using these lines in our controller

```
store.on('write',function(s,o){ editor.startEdit(record, 0); },me,{ single:true });
store.insert(0,record);
```

but it doesn't work. Meaning; the record get save, no error appears but the rowediting doesn't start.

We have a slightly modified version of buffered store which allow us to perform CRUD operations with it. Doing the same there opens the editor plugin.

**So how can we automatically start editing a row (and at best scroll to it first - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421508/how-to-scroll-to-a-specified-record-in-a-grid)) right after a inserted record was successfully written to the server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be facing a timing issue where your row still has the autoId created by the model and is yet not updated with the new Id provided by your server side. Because your Model is already updated the editor is not able to find the row you wants to edit and will abort.

Try to call the editor defered by using [Ext.Function.defer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-defer)

It may be worth a try.

Comment: Hmm ok, I will give it a try then

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the newly added row, you have to call `focusRow` on the grid's `view`.

`myGrid.getView().focusRow(row)` see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-focusRow for details.

What is your store's `batchUpdateMode`? I think the `write` event is fired only if the `batchUpdateMode` is `operation` (default value). Otherwise you can listen to `datachanged` event.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, this doesn't helped. The problem ist, that editor does not start edit (the startEdit() method returns false) without any error.